# Configure git ssh remote using intermediate host

Tags: git, ssh

Currently I don't have direct access to one of my git remotes. I can access it only through intermediate ssh host:  `ssh int-host` then `ssh remote` from int-host.

So, when I'm trying to push my commits to that remote host, I need to first push them on `int-host`:

1. Add one more remote on my local PC, pointing to int-host

   `git remote add int ssh://username@int-host:/path/to/repo`
2. Push two times

   `git push int master`

   `ssh int-host`

   `git push remote master`

Are there any ways to do it in one go?

One of variants that comes to my mind is using ssh port forwarding (something like `ssh -L2222:remote:22 int-host`) and configuring remote on my local pc respectively. However, this requires opening ssh connection to int-host.

Maybe, its possible to configure git, so that it could run ssh commands on push?

Comment: Don't know about git, but would a bash script do the trick?

Comment: What bash script? My goal is to make git to do most of the work, without my participation

Comment: I've meant that you write a script that does the everything under point 2. Of course you'd have to to it for pulling as well... Anyway, like I said - don't know about git, but with a script at least you run one command only...